# Gmail API - How to verify the APP to skip unverified screen

Tags: gmail-api

I have submitted my App with Gmail API for verification through consent screen. I am awaiting for the process to be completed, without any ETA from more than 10 days, but did not receive any response to date.

Is there any process to get verified quickly?

Comment: What you mean by verification is the "unverified app" screen before it displays the consent screen?

Comment: Yes.My app users getting that unverified screen before authentication.so I have submitted my app for google verification. But no response till date.

Comment: There's a [documentation](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en) regarding the unverified apps issue.